# GitLab CI with docker and laravel cannot connect to database

Tags: php, laravel, docker, gitlab

I have Gitlab CI set-up but it keeps failing when trying to run the database migrations:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = test_db and table_name = migrations)
```

My gitlab.yml file is:

```
before_script:
  - bash .gitlab-ci.sh
  - export APP_ENV=testing

services:
  - mysql:8.0

variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: testdb
  DB_HOST: mysql
  DB_USERNAME: root
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay

cache:
  paths:
  - vendor/
  - node_modules/

stages:
  - test
  - deploy

phpunit:php7.1:mysql8.0:
  stage: test
  image: php:7.1
  services:
    - mysql:8.0
  script:
    - echo "Running PHP Unit - php 7.1 mysql 8.0"
    - php vendor/bin/phpunit --colors

deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

    - ~/.composer/vendor/bin/envoy run deploy
  environment:
    name: production
    url: http://167.99.202.64

  when: manual
  only:
    - master
```

My before bash script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Install dependencies only for Docker.
[[ ! -e /.dockerinit ]] && [[ ! -e  /.dockerenv ]] && exit 0
set -xe

# Update packages and install composer and PHP dependencies.
apt-get update -yqq
apt-get install git libcurl4-gnutls-dev libicu-dev libmcrypt-dev libvpx-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libxpm-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev libxml2-dev libexpat1-dev libbz2-dev libgmp3-dev libldap2-dev unixodbc-dev libpq-dev libsqlite3-dev libaspell-dev libsnmp-dev libpcre3-dev libtidy-dev -yqq

# Compile PHP, include these extensions.
docker-php-ext-install mbstring mcrypt pdo_mysql curl json intl gd xml zip bz2 opcache

# Install Composer and project dependencies
echo 'Installing composer'
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar install --no-plugins --no-scripts --dev

# Copy over testing configuration.
cp .env.testing .env

# Generate an application key. Re-cache
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:cache

# Run database migrations
php artisan migrate
```

Finally my env.testing file:

```
APP_ENV=testing
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=key

DB_HOST=mysql
DB_DATABASE=test_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=testdb

CACHE_DRIVER=array
SESSION_DRIVER=array
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
MAIL_DRIVER=log
```

I'm guessing Laravel inside the PHP7.1 container can't see the MySQL container looking at the error message? Is declaring it as a service in the gitlab.yml not enough?

Answer (score 2):

Update your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and set mysql version to 5.7

```
services:
  - mysql:5.7
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally, i had same Problem with

```
service: -mysql:latest
```

(since three Weeks the Builds are failing, because the latest label has moved to version 8)

The Problem is:

MySQL 8

When running a PHP version before 7.1.16, or PHP 7.2 before 7.2.4, set MySQL 8 Server's default password plugin to mysql_native_password or else you will see errors similar to The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] even when caching_sha2_password is not used. [[1]](http://php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can redeclare an entrypoint for the MySql service like this:

```
services:
        - name: mysql:8.0
          alias: mysql-server
          entrypoint: ['/entrypoint.sh', '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password']
```